# .htaccess not working with laravel on production server-Shared hosting

Tags: php, apache, laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess in the laravel installation directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And this .htaccess in the `public` directory of the laravel installation directory (this one came with the laravel)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

So, if I access the root/installation directory in the browser, like this `http://something` where `something` is the installation directory and has it's own `virtual host` on `localhost`, then it works and if I access it like this `http://something/public` then it works too. **But this setup doesn't work on the production server**. If I access my website(which is a subdomain) on production server like this `http://sub.something.com` then it doesn't work, this shows me **Page not found error**, but this works `http://sub.something.com/public`

What am I doing wrong?

*I have namecheap.com shared hosting*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On share hosting subdomain, it's good your folder structure look like this:
I assume it's a linux server (Apache)

```
--public_html
----subdomainFolderName (content of public folder)
-------.htaccess
-------index.php
-------etc
-------laravelFolder [Public folder will not be inside here]
----------app
----------bootstrap
----------config
----------etc
```

Edit `subdomainFolderName/index.php`
Change line 22

`require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';`

TO

```
require __DIR__.'/laravelFolder/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

Change line 36 `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`

TO

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/laravelFolder/bootstrap/app.php';
```

This way you will not have issues with `.htaccess` and your URL will not contain `/public`

Comment: That's interesting. Seems more logical. Let me give it a try.

Comment: That's smooth :) Thanks. This is what I always prefer.